# How can I get WebStorm to show me a list of bower packages?

Tags: node.js, npm, bower, webstorm

Good morning.

My setup:

- OSX El Capitan 10.11.2
- JetBrains WebStorm 11.0.2
- Node.js 4.2.3
- NPM version 2.14.7
- Bower 1.7.0

Npm's prefix to`~/.npm-global`

My executable path is set: `$PATH = /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/mike/.npm-global/bin`

Running `bower search [package] --json` from the command line does return results.

The relevant lines (when Webstorm runs the search) from my log look like:

`2015-12-10 10:11:20,252 [1087432]   INFO - ipt.bower.BowerCommandLineUtil - Running bower command: /usr/local/bin/node /Users/mike/.npm-global/bin/bower search --json 
2015-12-10 10:11:20,739 [1087919]   WARN - .BowerAvailablePackagesManager - [parse all bower packages] Top-level element should be object, but BEGIN_OBJECT found.`

I did note that `bower search --json` (like Webstorm does, without specifying a package) returns bower usage information as a json object, which is funny, and I'm fairly confident this is the problem. There are no relevant issues on the Webstorm forums.

This is really taking the 'I' out of 'IDE'.

Can anybody offer a solution?

[Here's what I'm seeing (or not seeing).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ty8ed.png)

**UPDATE:** I was correct in my original assumption but I lack the expertise and time to solve it properly. My workaround is shown below. Bower's `search` command is supposed to run without arguments but, when Webstorm calls `bower search --json`, the command is interpreted as incorrect and returns the search usage as a json object. Silly stuff. Hope this helps somebody else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is caused by recent changes in Bower (https://github.com/eppeters/bower/commit/5a1e5eb9c717b4210d6a4af77eca1951bdd9f288); it now requires a module name neing passed to `search` command (though documentation hasn't yet been updated accordingly).
Related JetBrains ticket: [WEB-19389](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-19389); fixed, fix will be available in next update

Answer (score 0):

*This is a gross fix and is unsuitable for use as long as there is any hair remaining on your head:*

In `[npm prefix]/bin/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/util/cli.js`

I added the following to intercept the command line options and force an empty search pattern:

```
function readOptions() {

    ...

    noptOptions = nopt(types, shorthands, argv);

    ...

    // ADDED THE FOLLOWING

    if (noptOptions.argv.original.length == 2 && noptOptions.argv.original[0] == 'search' && noptOptions.argv.original[1] == '--json') {
    noptOptions.argv = {
        remain: ['search', ''],
        cooked: ['search', '', '--json'],
        original: ['search', '', '--json']
    };

    //////////////////////

    ...
}
```